# How to get ImageView xml R,drawable.img id in android

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

Is there any way so that I can get R.drawble.img id from the imageView which has some image with src @drawable/img. I mean if I had an image with src @drawable/img and I wanted to get the R.drawable.xxxx of that imageView. Is that possible??

I am asking because I have atleast 50 imageViews which I wanted to share whenever any of them is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To get Drawable from Imageview

```
imageview.getDrawable();
```

To get image in Bitmap form

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable);
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
```

To get ResourceId

use this this

```
int resId=Integer.parseInt(imageView.getTag().toString());
```

Comment: I want drawable resource Id and not the drawable itself

Answer (score 0):

You can get the drawable like

```
Drawable myDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
```

You can compare it with a drawable resource like

```
if(imageView.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)){
    //do work here
}
```

Comment: Sorry but no such method exists.

Comment: @ss007 Check my edited answer. If problem exists let me know.

Comment: no for this we have to know R.drawable.img in before hand. I wanted the R.drawable.xxx int value because I have approx 50 img views(each of them has src img) and I dont wanna write conditions for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get drawable ResourceId, because ImageView doesn't save it.

But you can use another method.
First of all you can set image src parameter from program code, that help you understand which ResourceId has concrete ImageView.

Second variant you can use hack. You can use tag parameter for save ResourceId in ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_profile_photo"
    android:tag="@drawable/icon_profile_photo"/>
```

After it you can get ResourceId from code by:

```
imageView.getTag()
```